# babel jsx SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm a learner of react and run into a bug that I don't know how to solve.

I first write the code on codepen, and it runs without problem. Here is the link to my [codepen](http://codepen.io/lianliu/pen/yOXmaX). After exporting it to the local machine, I setup the webpack to handle the compilation. And I receive the error of unexpected token.

After reading all the answers with this title, I still can't solve my bug.
I've updated my webpack cofig file according to the answers, re-installed the dependencies, used a couple of other react boilerplates([1](https://github.com/rbartoli/react-boilerplate), I currently use this one, but I've also tried some other react starter templates). After I remove the code that the console indicates, I've got another bug pointing to other place in the code.

Thanks in advance.

And here are my codes.

part of the webpack.config.js:

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015']
    }
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
    "env": {
        "development": {
            "presets": ["react-hmre"]
        }
    }
}
```

CommentList.js:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import Comment from './Comment'

class CommentList extends Component {
    render() {
        const CommentNodes = this.props.data.map((comment)=>{
            return (
                <Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id}>{comment.txt}<Comment/>
            )
        })
        return (
            <div className="commentList">
                <h2>Comments:</h2>
                {CommentNodes}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

CommentList.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

export default CommentList
```

the error:

> /Users/liulian/Documents/React-flux/react-boilerplate/src/components/commentBox/CommentList.js
>
> 22:9  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token
>
> Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/liulian/Documents/React-flux/react-boilerplate/src/components/commentBox/CommentList.js: Unexpected token (22:8)

Points to lines of code below, beginning from line 21 to line 25:

```
CommentList.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

export default CommentList
```

Comment: Is that a typo in CommentList ending tag. You have a slash at the end. It should be </Comment> instead of <Comment/>

Comment: `<Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id}>{comment.txt}<Comment/>` should be `<Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id}>{comment.txt} />`

Comment: @agent_hunt, after I correct this, the error changes to from Comment.js. I update it in my question.

Comment: @agent_hunt,  It turns out to be because the complier can't recognize the tab in one line of code in Comment.js. I use spaces instead, and it solves. But I'm confused that how to debug in react if the console doesn't provide relevant errors.

Comment: I think it  could be due to linting plugins used by your template.  When you run the webpack dev server  you usually get some messages  on the console depending on webpack config. Try adding these   quiet: false,
  colors: true,
  noInfo: false, to your devServer attribute in webpack.config.babel.js

Comment: @agent_hunt, thanks. Btw, after adding what you say, what do I expect? I don't see any difference.

Comment: The console where you started npm start should show errors/messages etc. Try making some syntax error and saving the file.